# Which ways do I have to import my tables and data from SQL Server to SQL Azure?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

I'm looking for the easiest way to import data from SQL Server to SQL Azure.

I'd like to work locally, would there be a way to synchronize my local database to SQL Azure all the time?

The thing is I wouldn't like to update each time I add a table in my local database to SQL Azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I HIGHLY recommend using the SQL Database Migration Wizard: http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/ it is the best free tool I've used so far.  Simple and works much easier the the SSMS and VS built in tools.  I think the Red-Gate tools now work well with SQL Azure too - but I haven't had a chance to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at SQL Data Sync?  A new October update just came out today.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh456371

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx) (**SSDT**) was developed by Microsoft to make it easy to deploy your DB to Azure.

Here's a detailed explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156163.aspx or http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/04/19/migrating-a-database-to-sql-azure-using-ssdt.aspx

and here's how to automate the process of publishing: http://www.anujchaudhary.com/2012/08/sqlpackageexe-automating-ssdt-deployment.html

To look: [SQL Server Data Tools Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/)

Answer (score 0):

There are  a few ways to migrate databases, I would recommend you to do it by using the generate scripts Wizard.

Here are the steps to follow

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee621790.aspx

Also there are others tools like Microsoft Sync Framework.

Here you'll find more information about it

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee730904.aspx